# Any of you aviation enthusiasts here interested in personal use of Drones?

Tags: discussion

If you are, please support the [Drone Stack Exchange Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63158/diy-drones?referrer=7ZWkRL29L0Z5vddNUSbPEA2)!

Then we can start sharing information on cool aviation tools such as this:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the proposal no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

As a Civil Air Patrol cadet, an programmer, and a aeronautical enthusiast, you can count on my support! This looks like it could be a very useful resource for people developing/using drones. I am going to keep an eye on this one!